# How to fix NPM package Tar, with high vulnerability about Arbitrary File Overwrite, when package is up to date?

Tags: npm-install, tar, node-sass, flickity, npm-audit

I just installed Flickity from NPM and got an NPM Audit Security Report after running `npm audit` stating that I have a high vulnerability issue regarding *Arbitrary File Overwrite* on package **tar** which is a dependency of **node-sass** as you can see here:

```
High......................... Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     
Package...................... tar                                                          
Patched in................... >=4.4.2                                                      
Dependency of................ node-sass [dev]                                              
Path......................... node-sass > node-gyp > tar                                   
More info.................... https://npmjs.com/advisories/803
```

Running `npm audit fix` didn't solve the problem as the vulnerability requires manual review. The recommendation at the *more info* link says to upgrade to version `4.4.2` or later. When I ran `npm show tar version` I realized I'm running version `4.4.8` so that confused me. I went to *`package-lock.json`* and realized **node-gyp, which is a dependency of node-sass, is using tar version ^2.0.0**

This is confusing me since I've seen many different tar versions as a dependency of other packages but this `node-sass > node-gyp > tar version` is the only one bellow `v4.4.2`. Why does it work like that, **why do I have to manually fix it and how can I manualy fix/upgrade this one tar package?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is being tracked on the gitgub page

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2625

Answer (score 5):

Please update the value for "tar" in your "package-lock.json" file. And to verify, run "`[npm audit][1]`".

```
"tar": {
      "version": "4.4.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-4.4.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "value",
      "dev": true,
      "optional": true,
      "requires": {
        "block-stream": "*",
        "fstream": "^1.0.2",
        "inherits": "2"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your package-lock.jason update tar for node to below (v 4.4.8):

"version": "4.4.8",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-4.4.8.tgz"

Comment: npm might overwriet these settings so:
use npm ci to load your settings from package-lock.jason file instead of package.jason

Comment: You're comment did for me what no other answer did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [SASS github issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2625#issuecomment-482519446): 
open package-lock.json
Find "tar"
Which should look like this:

```
"version": "2.2.1",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz",
"integrity": "sha1-jk0qJWwOIYXGsYrWlK7JaLg8sdE=",
```

Replace those 3 lines with:

```
"version": "4.4.8",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-4.4.8.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-LzHF64s5chPQQS0IYBn9IN5h3i98c12bo4NCO7e0sGM2llXQ3p2FGC5sdENN4cTW48O915Sh+x+EXx7XW96xYQ==",
```

delete the folder:

```
node_modules\npm
npm i
npm audit fix
npm audit
```

**Tada!**

Comment: No need to do that. `npm audit fix` alone will repair it since this issue has been solved and closed as you can see here https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2625 (approved answer above)