# How to fix tar version in package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, tar

My issue is pretty much similar to this: [How to fix NPM package Tar, with high vulnerability about Arbitrary File Overwrite, when package is up to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638180/how-to-fix-npm-package-tar-with-high-vulnerability-about-arbitrary-file-overwri)

Installed node v17.2.0 and npm v8.2.0 using brew on a Mac. `npm audit` keeps giving me these three vulnerabilities

```
# npm audit report

tar  <=4.4.17
Severity: high
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite on Windows via insufficient relative path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5955-9wpr-37jh
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning using symbolic links - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9r2w-394v-53qc
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite due to insufficient absolute path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3jfq-g458-7qm9
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r628-mhmh-qjhw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/tar
  tar-pack  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of tar
  node_modules/tar-pack
    create-react-app  >=1.3.0-alpha.58689133
    Depends on vulnerable versions of tar-pack
    node_modules/create-react-app

3 high severity vulnerabilities
```

It says fix is available via `npm audit fix` and I try that but it doesn't change anything.

*package-lock.json* file tells me that the *tar* version is 6.1.11 and so does `npm show tar version`. The only place where I find a tar version <= 4.4.17 is under the tar-pack dependencies. I tried to manually change it to 6.1.11. But, it magically reverts back whenever I try use `npm audit fix`.

I have no idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try npm audit fix --force instead.